# Boolean simplification gives two different results

Tags: logic, boolean-algebra

Here is the question I'm trying to solve:

> Use algebraic manipulation to find the minimum sum-of-products expression for the function $f=x_1x_3+x_1\overline{x}_2+\overline{x}_1x_2x_3+\overline{x}_1\overline{x}_2\overline{x}_3$

The way I attempted it was as follows:

```
f = ac + ab' + a'bc + a'b'c'
  = ac + b'(a + a'c') + a'bc   [distributive]
  = c(a + a'b) + b'(a + a'c')  [distributive]
  = c(a + b) + b'(a + c')      [using x + x'y = x + y]
  = ac + bc + ab' + b'c'
```

where a = x1, b = x2, c = x3

The correct answer, however is:

> $f=x_1x_3+x_2x_3+\overline{x}_2\overline{x}_3$

Can anyone tell me where I went wrong?

Comment: Next time, put the question and answer here directly, or at least a summary, rather than using links to external images

Comment: You did't quite go wrong.  You just missed one simplification.  The $x_1\bar{x}_2$ term is redundant.

Comment: You're right, but how is x1x2' redundant? I don't quite see it...

Comment: One way to see it is in user10354138's answer.  Another way is to note that it is the consensus term of the first and third terms.  Consensus terms are redundant.

Comment: @FabioSomenzi Yes, I've clearly missed that! A little reordering and consensus was the key. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\begin{align} &ac + bc + ab' + b'c'\\=~&bc +~ ac + ab' + b'c'\\ =~& bc+~(abc+ab'c)+(ab'c+ab'c')+(ab'c'+a'b'c')\\\vdots~~& \\ =~& bc+~ac+b'c'\\=~& ac+bc+b'c' \end{align} $

Complete the missing steps, and you are done.

Comment: Thanks for answering. The missing steps is where I'm stuck. For instance, where'd the ab' disappear to?

Comment: Look carefully at the three statements in brackets.  Do you notice any thing?  [Hint: idempotence] @StaticCrazee

Answer (score 0):

You haven't simplified it completely:
$$
x_1\bar{x_2}=x_1\bar{x_2}(x_3+\bar{x_3})=x_1\bar{x_2}x_3+x_1\bar{x_2}\bar{x_3}.
$$
The first term contains $x_1x_3$ and the second term contains $\bar{x_2}\bar{x_3}$.  So $x_1\bar{x_2}$ is redundant in your $f$.

Comment: Not the most complete answer

Answer (score -1):

Karnough maps are more standard and consistent than algebra, but algebra works too. You are almost there. Observe that bc + b'c' is true iff b$\equiv$c. If this is the case, then ac + ab'$\iff$a(c+b')$\iff$a. On the other hand, if bc + b'c' is false, then b$\equiv$c' and ac + ab'$\iff$a(c+b')$\iff$ac. So either the bc + b'c' term makes the expression true, or ac + ab' is equivalent to just ac.

Comment: Thanks for answering. But that doesn't match the answer?